# jQuery plugin function does not work in Firefox...but works in IE

Tags: jquery, firefox, plugins, internet-explorer-8

I have a html file which refers to a .js file. The js file has a jQuery function defined as a plugin. There are a few hyper-links in the html file..which when clicked should expand showing detailed description (which is hidden on the page). Now this arrangement works under IE8 but does not on Fire Fox. I initially had Firefox 3.6.13 ....and upgraded it to Firefox 4...it did not work for either versions. Here is a dummy html file(to keep it simple) and .js file contents

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
   <style>
    span { background:#def3ca; padding:3px; float:left; }
   </style>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
   <script src="path/to/jquery/file/jquery.compand.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td width="13%" valign="top">Job Code&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="87%" valign="top">Job Title&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">2223&nbsp;</td>
    <td valign="top"><a class="click" id="2223" href="#">Systems Analyst &nbsp;</a>
        <div class="text" id="2223text"><span>This text was hidden before.</span></div>
     </td> 
  </tr>
<script>$(".click").compand();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my js file containing jQuery plugin defining compand() function.

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.compand = function(){
        return this.click(function() {
            alert('item id: '+this.id);
            $("#"+this.id+"text").toggle("slow");   
        });     
    }; 
})(jQuery);
```

What further surprises me is if instead of having a .js file I have the following code embedded in html file between  tags....it works well on Firefox and IE8 both. Here is the script:

```
<script>
$('.click').click(function() {
    // get id of the clicked item
    alert('id clicked: ' + this.id);
    $("#"+this.id+"text").toggle('slow', 
        function() {
            alert('Animation complete.');
        });
});
</script>
```

I require to have this function as a jQuery Plugin so that I do not replicate the above code on several html pages. Thanks for reading so far! Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a reason for this behavior and its quite embarrassing for me to mention how I messed. Luceos thanks for your inputs!.. they have certainly helped me.

After another day of breaking my head over it...I figured out that the path-to-jquery plugin was something that Firefox was finding hard to figure out. Let me explain it here:
I had the following setup. I had both .html and .js file on my Desktop and as you can see below I provided fully-qualified-path to point to my jQuery function.

`<script src="C:\\Users\\******\\***\\testjQuery\\jquery.compand.js"></script>` (Windows separator)
OR
`<script src="C:/Users/****/****/testjQuery/jquery.compand.js"></script>`(Unix separator)

IE8 is able to figure both and pick up the .js file correctly but FireFox (3.6.13 and 4.0)did not.

Instead when I provided a relative path i.e. in the same context:

```
<script src=jquery.compand.js"></script>
```

(since my .html and .js file are exactly in same folder)
Now this works on both FireFox and IE 8

Answer (score 0):

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.compand = function(){
        return this.click(function() {
            var openID = jQuery(this).attr("id");
            $("#"+openID+"text").toggle("slow");   
        });     
    }; 
})(jQuery);
```

What about this approach and what errors do you get?

Comment: Hi Luceos thanks for a very quick response!! I tested by replacing your function in my jQuery plugin and I still get the same results i.e. works in IE8 but neither in Firefox 4 or 3.6.16. I have firebug installed and it points to the following line in html file that calls the plugin..but doesnt explicitly mention anything. Here is what it says:                                        $(".click").compand is not a function

[Break On This Error] $(".click").compand();

Comment: Where do you insert your compand javascript? After including jquery?

Comment: Hi Luceos, thanks for your response again! As per my html file, I include the compand javascript in the <head> and the call to this .js is made in the <body>. Please refer to sample html file I posted in my original question. I hope I answered your question please let me know

Comment: How about adding type="text/javascript" to the script includes?